# Solidity and Web3js codes are not working inside the private Ethereum(geth) network but same codes are working in public ethereum

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, web3js, remix, private-blockchain

```
 geth version : 1.9.0-stable-52f24617,
 node version : v10.16.3,
 npm version  : 6.9.0,
 web3 version : -- web3@1.0.0-beta.36.
```

genesis.json:

```
{
"config": {
"chainId": 9663080,
"homesteadBlock": 0,
"eip150Block": 0,
"eip155Block": 0,
"eip158Block": 0,
"byzantiumBlock": 0,
"Ethash": {
  "period": 15,
  "epoch": 30000
}
},
"nonce": "0x0",
"timestamp": "0x5d5769ad",
"gasLimit": "0x7FFFFFFFFFFFF",
"difficulty": "0x1",
"mixhash"    : "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
"alloc": {
"0x02731Eb61f258C104F1BB4191cF715d8D1014CD3": {
  "balance": "0x200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
}
 },
"number": "0x0",
"gasUsed": "0x0",
"parentHash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
}
```

1. In geth deployment of the smart contract is working, while calling 
   functionalities I am facing some issues.

2.both web3 code and solidity codes are working in public ethereum but the 
  same codes are not working in private network(geth).

3. Is there any problem with my geth or genesis.json.

Web3js error:

```
    Error: Returned values aren't valid, did it run Out of Gas?
at ABICoder.decodeParameters (/home/nithin/project/ConnectedVehicles/node_modules/web3-eth-abi/src/index.js:226:15)
at Contract._decodeMethodReturn (/home/nithin/project/ConnectedVehicles/node_modules/web3-eth-contract/src/index.js:465:22)
at Method.outputFormatter (/home/nithin/project/ConnectedVehicles/node_modules/web3-eth-contract/src/index.js:818:46)
at Method.formatOutput (/home/nithin/project/ConnectedVehicles/node_modules/web3-core-method/src/index.js:163:54)
at sendTxCallback (/home/nithin/project/ConnectedVehicles/node_modules/web3-core-method/src/index.js:473:33)
at /home/nithin/project/ConnectedVehicles/node_modules/web3-core-requestmanager/src/index.js:147:9
at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (/home/nithin/project/ConnectedVehicles/node_modules/web3-providers-http/src/index.js:91:13)
at XMLHttpRequestEventTarget.dispatchEvent (/home/nithin/project/ConnectedVehicles/node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist/xml-http-request-event-target.js:34:22)
at XMLHttpRequest._setReadyState (/home/nithin/project/ConnectedVehicles/node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist/xml-http-request.js:208:14)
at XMLHttpRequest._onHttpResponseEnd (/home/nithin/project/ConnectedVehicles/node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist/xml-http-request.js:318:14)
at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/home/nithin/project/ConnectedVehicles/node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist/xml-http-request.js:289:61)
at emitNone (events.js:111:20)
at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:208:7)
at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1064:12)
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:139:11)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:181:9)
```

I connected to the private(geth) from the remix and I deployed the smart contract and(1) while calling functionality data is not coming. and 
(2)in the hash column, it is showing call+transaction hash

[image: remix status bar]

Comment: can you add the error

Comment: Which version of web3 and node are you using ?

Comment: Try Downgrading node. There are a lot of bugs/ compatibility issues with node 12z

Comment: does it work if you deploy it on ganache private network?

Comment: @haxerl yes, It is working in ganache-cli

Comment: @SanjaySB I updated the question so please check and help me.

Comment: @SamuelDare I updated the question so please check and help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed genesis.json now it is working

```
{
"config": {
"chainId": 9663080,
"homesteadBlock": 0,
"eip150Block": 0,
"eip150Hash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
"eip155Block": 0,
"eip158Block": 0,
"byzantiumBlock": 0,
"constantinopleBlock": 0,
"petersburgBlock": 0,
"ethash": {}
},
"nonce": "0x0",
"timestamp": "0x5d5cdc87",
"extraData": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
"gasLimit": "0x47b760",
"difficulty": "0x80000",
"mixHash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
"coinbase": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
"alloc": {
"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000": {
  "balance": "0x1"
},
"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000001": {
  "balance": "0x1"
},
"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000002": {
  "balance": "0x1"
},
"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000003": {
  "balance": "0x1"
}
},
"number": "0x0",
"gasUsed": "0x0",
"parentHash": 
"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
}
```